# How can i reverse the direction of this dc motor easily?

Tags: wiring, diagram

How can I easily reverse the spinning direction of the left motor? Thanks[image: diagram of what im working with]

Comment: Lookup an H-bridge transistor configuration for an easy way of switching the direction of a DC motor.

Answer (score 4):

You could reverse the direction of rotation of the motor by just interchanging its leads.